# Get a member object using reflection (or some other way)

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to be able to access a property or member of a class by name. I'm fine if it's a property:

```
  PropertyInfo prop = object.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
  object propValue = prop.GetValue(object, null);
```

Things seem a little trickier if it is a member/field. AFter studying `GetMember` and trying a bunch of different stuff I can't figure out how to just get a reference to the  object the same way it would be returned from `GetProperty`, if it was a property.

The other question is, is this the right way to accomplish this? In reading about reflection, it seems to have a lot of overhead. Is this just in comparison to not using reflection, or is it significant enough that I should think twice about developing something that will be doing this a lot, and what alternatives do I have, if any, to obtain a reference to a member of a class by name only?

Thanks for any insight. If it makes any difference, my goal is to be able to serialize an arbitrary named property or member of a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [GetField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e.aspx) instead of `GetProperty` if you want to retrieve a field.

```
FieldInfo field = object.GetType().GetField(fieldName);
object fieldValue = field.GetValue(Context.Parent);
```

> or is it significant enough that I should think twice about developing something that will be doing this a lot, and what alternatives do I have, if any, to obtain a reference to a member of a class by name only?

It is definitely expensive, but I'd profile it to determine if you will have a performance issue.

The other main option(s) is to build some form of dictionary yourself that maps "names" to values.  This can be a direct dictionary mapping to the value, or a dictionary that maps to a delegate which retrieves the value.  This does have the advantage in that you can make it work the same way for properties or fields, but each class needs to create the mapping.  (This can, however, potentially be done via reflection at construction time.)

> If it makes any difference, my goal is to be able to serialize an arbitrary named property or member of a class.

I would recommend reviewing the built-in [Serialization Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) prior to rolling your own version...

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for. This is serializing for Javascript, and yeah I'm using MS's already. Performance is not an issue at this point but I'm trying to consider scalability as I design this. The caching idea is probably quite applicable here - though this is for web applications. The properties will need to be accessed each time a page loads. I don't think caching delegates would work across page loads as the objects would not be the same instance. Any idea on a way to optimize or cache when the structure will persist, but not the instance?

Comment: @jamietre: You could cache a delegate that takes the instance into account (statically per type), ie: `Func<YourType, object>`, and then pass the instance into the delegate to get the value...

Comment: @Reed Copsley - I'll never need to access a given instance more than once. I will need to access different instances of the same signature many times, though. That is, once I get the info on a page load, I'm done with it for that particular page load. Wouldn't this result in an ever-growing cache because `object` is different each time? Perhaps I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: @jamietre: If you have your type create a static cache of delegates (that map property names -> Func<YourType, object>), you could call that delegate on each page load, passing the instnace to the delegate.  The cache would be a constant size (one per field/property/etc).

Comment: I'm still being stupid, I apologize, and I do really want to understand this. Why wouldn't the delegate in the cache refer to a then-defunct object on a successive page load?

Comment: The delegate would be a delegate that was static, where the instance is passed in.  Say your class is named Foo, you'd make it a `Func<Foo,object>` - the lambda would look like:  `var del = foo => foo.Property;`.  The trick is that, when you call it from your page, you'd call it as:  `object result = del(this.YourFooInstance);`  (Normally, you'd make it a `Func<object>` defined on the instance - in this case, you'd pass the instance in as an argument instead)

Comment: Ahhh... light goes on. That looks like a perfect solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Reed I came up with an implementation but I'm not sure I'm quite there. I'm caching a delegate to propinfo.GetValue(), I couldn't figure out how to save the delegate to the property directly, since I don't have compile time access to "foo.Property" -- if you have a sec can you tell me if what I did makes sense? It is essentially the same? Posted as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# 4.0 (released alongside the .NET Framework 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010), there's the new `dynamic` keyword that will simplify things in your code:

```
dynamic myValue = anyObject;
string name = myValue.myField; // Resolved at runtime, not compile-time
bool result = myValue.myBooleanMethod(1, 2, 3); // Ditto
```

etc.  My understanding is that this does more-or-less the same thing under the hood as using reflection and testing for the existence of compatible `PropertyInfo`/`MethodInfo`/etc. and then invoking them, so performance is still a concern, but it's certainly a lot more readable.

Comment: I am using 4.0 - but I need to access them by a name not known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with for caching, comments welcome.

```
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, 
        Func<object, object[], object>> ReflectionCache
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ReflectionCache==null) {
                _ReflectionCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<Type, string>,
                  Func<object, object[], object>>();
            }
            return _ReflectionCache;
        }
    } private static ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, 
         Func<object, object[], object>> _ReflectionCache = null;

    public static object GetCachedProperty(object obj, string name)
    {
        Func<object,object[],object> del;
        if (!ReflectionCache.TryGetValue(Tuple.Create<Type,string>(obj.GetType(),
          name), out del)) {
            MemberInfo memberInfo = 
               (MemberInfo)obj.GetType().GetMember(name).GetValue(0);
            PropertyInfo prop = null;
            FieldInfo fld = null;

            switch(memberInfo.MemberType) {
            case MemberTypes.Field:
                fld = obj.GetType().GetField(name);
                break;
            case MemberTypes.Property:
                prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(name);
                break;
            }

            if (prop == null && fld == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("No property or field named '" + name 
                 + "' could be found in the context parent.");
            }
            if (prop!=null) {
                prop= obj.GetType().GetProperty(name);
                del = prop.GetValue;
            } else {
                fld = obj.GetType().GetField(name);
                del = delegate(object cls,object[] index) {
                    return fld.GetValue(cls);
                };
            }

            ReflectionCache[Tuple.Create<Type,string>(obj.GetType(),name)]=del;
        }
        return(del(obj,null));
    }
```

Comment: For properties, you can use Delegate.CreateDelegate on the PropertyInfo's GetGetMethod, which will avoid the reflection overhead...

Comment: Cool. Thanks again. I'm guessing there's still a benefit for fields since I'm only using GetValue and not GetField too.